Firebase Cloud Functions Unauthorized Issue
I'm implementing a user login feature using Google and Apple Sign-In. The Firebase Authentication works, and I can see the authenticated user in the Firebase Console. I'm also able to fetch the user's token as shown below:
guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            print("No authenticated user found.")
            return
        }
user.getIDTokenResult { tok, error in
            print(tok?.token)
        }

However, when I call my Firebase Cloud Function, I get an unauthorized error. Here's the code for calling the function:
Functions.functions().httpsCallable("handleUserLogin").call(["uid": "uid", "email": "email"]) { (result, error) in
            print(error)
            print(result)
        }

I also tried calling the function using cURL, but the same error occurs.
Debugging Steps Taken:
App Check: Not enabled.
Firebase Security Rules: Set to open (allow read, write: if true;).
Token: Verified that the token is generated and present.
Here’s the code for my Cloud Function:
server code :
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
// const serviceAccount = require("./service-account.json");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.handleUserLogin = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        console.log("Authentication context:", context.auth);

    if (!context.auth) {
        console.error("Unauthenticated request");
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            "unauthenticated",
            "The user must be authenticated to access this function."
        );
    }

    console.log("Authenticated user UID:", context.auth.uid);
        // Debug: Test Firestore write
        const testRef = admin.firestore().collection("test").doc("testDoc");
        try {
            await testRef.set({ test: "testValue" });
            console.log("Firestore test write successful.");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Firestore test write failed:", error);
        }

        // Process user login
        const { uid, email } = data;

        if (!uid || !email) {
            console.error("Invalid arguments: UID or Email missing");
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
                "invalid-argument",
                "UID and Email are required."
            );
        }

        const userRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid);

        try {
            const doc = await userRef.get();

            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log("User exists:", doc.data());
                return { profile: doc.data(), newUser: false };
            } else {
                const newUser = {
                    email,
                    createdAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                };
                console.log("Creating new user profile:", newUser);

                await userRef.set(newUser);
                console.log("New user created successfully.");

                return { profile: newUser, newUser: true };
            }
        } catch (firestoreError) {
            console.error("Firestore operation failed:", firestoreError);
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", "Firestore operation failed.");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error handling user login:", error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", error.message || "An unexpected error occurred.");
    }
});

Observations
The context.auth object in the function seems to be undefined, suggesting the user isn't authenticated when the function is invoked.
Security rules are not an issue since they're fully open.
Question
Why am I receiving an unauthorized error when invoking this Cloud Function? How can I ensure that the user is properly authenticated when calling the function?

What acls apply to the cloud function itself? Do you have invoker permission?

that is open as well, i have a test api that is just to add something to firestore and it works. im also the owner of the project.
